# git_commit_create_v create empty commits

Tags: c, libgit2

I've been trying to create a new commit using libgit2 on a simple program:

Thats what I did:

I've got a repository, and added a few files on index by path:

```
  git_index_add_bypath(my_repo_index, filename);

  //Create commit signature
  const char *email, *name;
  git_config_get_string(&email, cfg, "user.email");
  git_config_get_string(&name, cfg, "user.name");
  git_signature_now(&signature, name, email);

  //get last commit => parent
  git_revparse_single(&git_obj, repo, "HEAD");
  git_oid *parent_oid = (git_oid *)git_obj; 

  git_commit_lookup(&parent, repo, parent_oid);

  //writing index
  git_oid tree_oid;
  git_index_write_tree(&tree_oid, my_repo_index);

  git_tree *tree;
  git_tree_lookup(&tree, repo, &tree_oid);

  //Create the commit
  git_commit_create_v(
    &new_commit_id,
    repo,
    "HEAD",
    signature, //author
    signature, //commiter
    NULL, /* use default message encoding */
    msg,
    tree,
    1, // qty of parents
    parent //parent commit
  );
```

I thought that everything was OK, 
The files are being added on index, and the commit is being created on HEAD with it's parent as the latest commit on the HEAD.

But the commit is empty ???

I did a git log and the commit is there, but if I did a git show (SHA) I got nothing.
BTW the files added on index stay there after the commit it's created.

Comment: An "empty" commit means it has the same tree as its parent, so have you checked for that? What ids do you get out of each? Is the file really changed on-disk? What does `git status` return if you write out the index (`git_index_write()`)?

Comment: git status return the files added on [staged]. I added the files on index, and got the tree_id through the git_index_write_tree function. I'll check if this function is returning the same tree id as "HEAD^{tree}"